# Node LDAP/AD hashing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory, azure-active-directory, ldap

I'm having both of a backend and a frontend, my backend running on Node, my Frontend as a simple BrowserApp.

I'm using the node-module activedirectory2 to verify a user on our AD-Server.

But ad.authenticateUser(username, password) only takes PlainText as password... and I really don't want to send the password from the frontend with a simple "encryption", even tho I'm using TLS 1.3

I'm searching the entire internet for a module which takes hashed values as input to compare credentials. Is there a good way to pass a hashed value to the AD? Or should I be "safe" sending PlainText over TLS 1.3?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a good way to pass a hashed value to the AD?

No, there is no way to pass hashed values to AD.

> Or should I be "safe" sending PlainText over TLS 1.3?

If it's using TLS, it's not plain text. It's encrypted. TLS is the encryption of the internet in general, including your bank's website. It's safe.